# How to disable Apple Watch SOS crash detection temporarily out of app?

Tags: crash, apple-watch, swift

I'm currently developing a Apple Watch App for surfers. I've received many requests if we can pause or disable the crash detection of a watch in case our surfers app is running to prevent automatic SOS calls during crashes on water (which happens a lot during freestyle).

Has anybody came around this topic so far?

Is this even allowed by Apple?

I've researched a lot but can not find anything about this topic.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/guide/watch-ultra/apd392ca7d75/watchos) help you ?

Comment: @PtitXav sure, but that's not “smart” at all ;) Would be nice if an app could toggle this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do.

There's currently no API for the crash detection feature. If an API emerges, I imagine it would be similar to the one for fall detection (CMFallDetectionManager) which provides insigts into the events, but no way of pausing or disabling SOS calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think Apple will provide an API in future updates?

Comment: That is entirely speculation - I have no Apple insider source that tells me whether or not an API for crash detection will be made available for third party developers. Flip a coin and that would probably be the best guess.